# Finding singularities of A Function

Tags: singularity-theory

I want to find singularities of $$f(z)=\frac{{z}^{2}}{e^z + {e}^{-z} - 2}$$
I solved this problem but I am not sure about it. Is it correct?

$${e^z + {e}^{-z} - 2}= 0$$
Then I divide by $$e^{-z}$$
to get $${{e^{2z}} - 2{e}^{z} +1 }= 0$$
Letting $$x=e^z$$
Then
$$x^2-2x+1=0$$
$$(x-1)(x-1)=0$$
so $$e^z=1=e^{i2πk}$$
$$z= i2πk$$ Where k=0,1,-1,2,-2...

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct, but an easier way is to remark that $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{z^2}{\cosh(z)-1}$$
and thus
$$\cosh(z)=1\iff z=2i\pi n$$
with $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Or note that $1-\cosh z=2\sinh^2(z/2)=0\implies z/2=in\pi$

Comment: All these hyperbolic monsters look more frightening to me than the nice exponential. I would for sure run the calculations as MATH did.